# CLion 2017.1 CMake compile error on mac OS10.12

Tags: c++, macos, build, cmake, clion

I installed the CLion for mac. But when I create a "Hello, world" project, I got some problems. It seems like CMake failed to set system information or what.

This is my CMakeList.txt generated by CLion default:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
PROJECT(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Then I got the errors as below:

```
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled
> -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.1.0.8020038
> -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.1.0.8020038 CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:26
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)
> 
> 
> System is unknown to cmake, create: Platform/sysname:Darwin 
> nodename:Fez.local  release:16.5.0  version:Darwin Kernel Version
> 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64  machine:x86_64 to use this
> system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can
> be added to cmake Your CMakeCache.txt file was copied to
> CopyOfCMakeCache.txt. Please send that file to cmake@www.cmake.org.
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:38
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)
> 
> 
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:41
> (include):   include called with invalid argument:
> root:xnu-3789.51.2~3_RELEASE_X86_64
> 
>    machine:x86_64 Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)
> 
> 
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:48
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)
> 
> 
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:52
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)
> 
> 
> -- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:26
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2
> (project)
> 
> 
> System is unknown to cmake, create: Platform/sysname:Darwin 
> nodename:Fez.local  release:16.5.0  version:Darwin Kernel Version
> 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64  machine:x86_64 to use this
> system, please send your config file to cmake@www.cmake.org so it can
> be added to cmake CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:38
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2
> (project)
> 
> 
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:41
> (include):   include called with invalid argument:
> root:xnu-3789.51.2~3_RELEASE_X86_64
> 
>    machine:x86_64 Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2
> (project)
> 
> 
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:48
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2
> (project)
> 
> 
> CMake Error at
> /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:52
> (include):   include called with wrong number of arguments.  include()
> only takes one   file. Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:2
> (project)
> 
> 
> CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake
> failed
> -- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
> -- broken CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51
> (message):   The C compiler  
> "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc"
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
> 
>   It fails with the following output:
> 
>    
> 
>   
> 
>   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT)
> 
> 
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also
> "/Users/changeset/CLionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

When I first time run CLion project on mac, it runs perfectly. But after I compiled the cocos2d on XCode, these problems come. I have removed all the cocos2d files on my mac, but cmake still goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problems here. It seems to be unusual.

> The errors listed about CMake were caused by incorrectly invoking
>   `uname`.

I checked out the [CMake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/index.html), and I found that my mac produced the wrong [CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME.html#variable:CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME) results. And after test `uname` on my terminal, I found that maybe the kernel used wrong command. And then I `echo $PATH` found that my `$PATH` changed by cocos2d-x installed yesterday. The new `$PATH` include my `uname` programmed for study, and it overrided the kernel `uname`. After I delete `my uname`, clean CMake, restart CLion, everything is just going fine. Done.